# Adding dynamically DOM element by js, performance issue (DIV vs ListBox vs C#)

Tags: javascript, html

I try the follow code on my I7 with 64GB Ram. the result surprise me. There is a big difference between adding element as DIV child (2 sec) and Adding OPTION into ListBox(15 sec). Why?

After all I disapointed even about the 2 sec for DIV version. I notice that browser update the view only at end of JS block. So why is take longer then running loop over similar collection add operation?

For comparison reason, I try fill Winform DataGridView. If you fill it with no DataTable, it's take a long time, But if you use with DataTable, it's take nothing!

So in browser have a way to achieve this goal? Also why ListBox is so slow vs ListBox.

Here is code examples.

HTML with JS:

```js
function addListItem()
{
  lst = document.getElementById("lst");

  for(let c=0;c<30000;c++){
    n=document.createElement("option");
    n.text="Dynamic item " + c;    
    lst.options.add(n);  
  }  
}


function addTmpl()
{
  ph = document.getElementById("place_holder");
  t = document.getElementById("template");
  
  for(let c=0;c<30000;c++){
    n = t.cloneNode(true);
    n.id = "item";
    n.style.visibility="visible";
    ph.appendChild(n);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ss">
  <button onclick="addListItem()">Fill list</button>
  <button onclick="addTmpl()">Clone div</button>
</div>

<select id="lst" size="13" style="width:250"> 
  <option>Static item</option>
</select>


<div id="place_holder" style="background-color:yellow;margin:10px">Div Place holder</div>

<div id="template" style="visibility:hidden">Div item</div>

<script src="aa.js"></script>
```

And here the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmTestAddingItemsPrformance : Form
    {
        public frmTestAddingItemsPrformance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            t.Columns.Add("Column1");


            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
            {
                DataRow r = t.NewRow();
                r[0] = i.ToString();
                t.Rows.Add(r);                
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find it counter-intuitive at all that a select box (which requires interaction with the OS in most cases) is slower than a div (which doesn't). 30k items is ***far*** too many for a list box from a UX perspective. Put things in categories, and have the user navigate the categories such that they have a reasonable number of choices to work from, or use divs and an input users can use to type text to reduce the number of choices to only those matching.

Comment: Side note, because it's not the problem, but that code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in several places. Be sure to declare your variables.

Comment: Good research about DataGridView [link](https://10tec.com/articles/why-datagridview-slow.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The issue in all cases is the same - How many times you are rebuilding the control.
When working with HTML, you are re-rendering the DOM everytime you add a new element in your list. 
You can significantly improve your dom performance by reducing this.

so if you were to change your JS function as -

```
var selectList = document.getElementById('lst');

function addListItem() {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    elOption;
  for (var i=0; i<30000; ++i) {
    elOption = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    elOption.text = "Dynamic item " + i;;
  }
  selectList.appendChild(frag);
}
```

The function now uses a different API now - [createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

This creates the list in memory and updates the DOM only once.

Same thing happens on the WinForm application. When you bind the control once, it requires the control to be built only once. When you add 1 element at a time, the control has to be updated that many times.

Comment: Have you measured that? Because I had the same thought, but it didn't improve anything (at least, not by more than maybe 10%, tops).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: just tried it - 2 seconds on Edge, 12 seconds on Chrome. ~25 seconds on chrome/Edge with your function.

Comment: Which is about the same time that it takes without using the fragment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: no. for me using fragment is ~2x faster on Chrome and ~12x faster on Edge. Not sure why `Edge` is able to render it in 2 seconds compared to `chrome`. Try it yourself. I don't have `firefox` to test it.

Comment: As I said above: I did try it myself. My results were nothing like that good (using Chrome on \*nix).

Comment: For me it's seem the same performance, for direct use with createElement as indirect by createDocumentFragment. Notice, when I clone DIV or even create it, the 12 sec become 0 sec. so the "create element" is not the issue.